# Проксирование в nginx / открыть другой сайт не меняя текущий адрес

Tags: linux, nginx, веб-сервер, proxy, proxypass

Делаю проксирование с локального хоста на google. Задача слудующая:

1. В браузере ввожу proxy.localhost, нажимаю enter
2. Открывается google.com, но в браузере в адресной строке остаётся proxy.localhost (т.е. выполняется проксирование)

ПРОБЛЕМА. У меня работает как в случае редиректа, а не проксирования, т.е. после пункта 1 открывается google и запись в адресной строке меняется с proxy.localhost на https://www.google.com.

ВОПРОС. Как сделать так, чтобы адрес оставался proxy.localhost, но открывался https://www.google.com ?

Помогите пожалуйста, перепробовал множество вариантов, откатил до более менее рабочего, вот мой актуальный код:

```
server {
<------>listen *:80;
<------>server_name proxy.localhost;
<------>location / {
<------><------>    proxy_pass https://google.com/;
<------>}
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить  **proxy_set_header Host 'google.com';**

Comment: Уже так, но не помагает:
`server {
<------>listen *:80;
<------>server_name proxy.localhost;
<------>location / {
<------><------>    proxy_pass https://google.com/;
<------><------>    proxy_set_header Host google.com;
<------>}
}`

Comment: Никак. Гугл активно против и делает редирект на js.

Зачем вам вообще это надо? Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Тим лид задал такую задачу, на стажеровке...

Comment: Вот прямо с гуглом? Возможно он ожидал от вас вопроса «зачем?»

Comment: Alexey Ten, спасибо вам большое, проблема была именно в гугле. Проверил на другом сайте и там работает корректно